# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Controller#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

This may be a basic error and lots of people have ask similar questions.
However, none of them actually helped me solve the issue I am facing now.

The error is as followings;

```
Processing by SchedulesController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"123"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 123]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=123):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:17:in `correct_user'
```

What I'd like to do is to edit schedule content.
The above error was appeared when I typed the url such as `http://localhost:3000/schedules/123/edit`.

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

  private

    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

end
```

**schedules_controller.rb**

```
class SchedulesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :set_schedule,  only: %i(show edit update destroy)  

  def new
    @schedule = Schedule.new
    room = @schedule.rooms.build
    room.events.build
  end

  def create
    @schedule = current_user.schedules.build(schedule_params)
    if @schedule.save
      flash[:success] = "Schedule created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @schedule.update(schedule_params)
      flash[:success] = "Schedule updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

...  

  private

    def schedule_params
      params.require(:schedule).permit(:title, :departure_date,  room_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :room, :day])
    end

    def set_schedule
      @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  root  'schedules#index'
  get   'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get   'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post  'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete   'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :schedules
...

end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>Edit schedule</p>
    <%= render "schedule_form" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_schedule_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@schedule) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  <br>
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
    <%= f.label :departure_date %>
    <%= f.text_field :departure_date, class: 'form-control' %>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="fa fa-calendar glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :rooms do |a| %>
    <%= a.input :room %>
  <% end %>

  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Create my schedule", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <br>

<% end %>
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

...

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

end
```

**SOLVED!**

I created `correct_user` in both `users_controller.rb` and `schedules_controller.rb` instead of `application_controller.rb`.

**users_controller.rb**

```
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
```

**schedules_controller.rb**

```
    def correct_user
      @schedule = current_user.schedules.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) if @schedule.nil?
    end
```

Comment: have you checked in your controller what the value of `params[:id]` is? You can insert a breakpoint in there and also check if the record exists in the database. By the way, for a basic CRUD setup like this it might be easier to just create a scaffold and delete the stuff you don't need.

Comment: it seems `correct_user` method is not looking good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the same params[:id] for schedule

```
@schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
```

and User

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

in the before_action :correct_user

I suppose there is no such User record in your database. You should send different params for User and Schedule models

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @rubchick. Although I understand the reason, it would be appreciated if you could give me sample code.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue, you're checking current_user? . How do you check it? Please show your SessionHelper methods. You can simply write a method like 'current_user' and return current user id and call then in your 'correct_user' method: User.find(current_user)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @rubchick. I add SessionHelper in my question. I refer to [rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) and try to customize the code to suit my app.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @rubchick. When I use `@user = User.find(current_user)` instead of `@user = User.find(params[:id])` in the application_controller.rb, the user can edit other people's schedule. It would be appreciated if you could give me any advice.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue If you designed your models so schedule model belongs to user and user has many schedules you can just check if this very schedule belongs to this user. ex. schedule.user_id == current_user.id

Comment: Thank you,@rubchick. It worked after changing controller as I updated at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you could have added scope as none for modal User
See to your active record and User.rb class and make sure that scope is not null.

> http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

see in to null relation and you may get some idea