# Edit Article comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Objective is to edit the comment for its associated article.
Rails 7.0.4.3

Receiving error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#edit
Couldn't find Article with 'id'=#<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000001061950a8>
```

for this line within the 'def edit' comments_controller.rb file.

I've tried to follow this [nested edit path not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179637/nested-edit-path-not-working) and [ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Controller#edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120494/activerecordrecordnotfound-in-controlleredit) with no avail.

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comments = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article), status: :see_other
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
  end
end
```

**_comments.html.erb**

```
<%# unless comment.archived? %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>

<%= link_to "Edit comment", edit_article_comment_path(@article.comments) %>

<p>
  <%= link_to "Destroy comment", [comment.article, comment], data: {
    turbo_method: :delete,
    turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?"
  } %>
</p>
<%# end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
    root "articles#index"

    resources :articles do
      resources :comments
    end
end
```

**controllers/comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  # include Visible

  belongs_to :article
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your problem here is in the error itself and specifically -

```
'id'=#<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000001061950a8>
```

This is telling you that rails is searching for a record to edit by an `ID`, but you are supplying it with an Active Record Collection, which is a response of many records from your `has_many` association.

So now take a look at your `_comments.html.erb`,

```
<%= link_to "Edit comment", edit_article_comment_path(@article.comments) %>
```

Your path is spot on, but your `edit` action requires an `ID` not a collection of comments which is what you are supplying it with via `@article.comments`.

Now I'd suggest you loop through your `@article.comments`, but it looks like you're already there with `<%= comment.body %>` so, you simply need to replace your `path(ID)` with `comment`.

Some reading:

- https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html